# How to bring complex Application Insights to a Farmer deployment?

Tags: f#, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I got  interested in [Farmer](https://compositionalit.github.io/farmer/) and decided to try it out in my project. I managed to replace most of the ARM template with Farmer.

However, there are Application Insights left, as I have quite a complicated setup there, including some alerts, scheduled query rules and so on. Whereas everything that Farmer currently [supports](https://compositionalit.github.io/farmer/api-overview/resources/app-insights/) for AI is just name, IP masking and sample percentage.

How can I plug in AI setup into the Farmer so that I don't reject Farmer just because of that part? My service looks like this:

```ml
let webApp = webApp {
    name appName
    service_plan_name servicePlanName
    sku WebApp.Sku.B1
    always_on
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `webApp` setup has a builder keyword for this, `link_to_unmanaged_app_insights`:

> Instructs Farmer to link this webapp to an existing app insights instance that is externally managed, rather than creating a new one.

However there are no examples and only [one test](https://github.com/CompositionalIT/farmer/blob/17909aa278bd93159b84bf7c4f80de560c393356/src/Tests/WebApp.fs#L48) using it, so after some experimenting, this is what proved to work:

1. Keep having AI setup in ARM in the source code, e.g. `arm-template-ai.json`.
2. Note the AI resource Id.
3. Use the aforementioned keyword in the F# app setup:

```ml
let webApp = webApp {
    name appName
    service_plan_name servicePlanName
    sku WebApp.Sku.B1
    always_on
    link_to_unmanaged_app_insights (ResourceId.create appInsightsName)
}
```

4. In the release pipeline, **first** deploy AI from the AI ARM template in the source code.
5. Then deploy all other resources from the ARM template generated by Farmer.

---

An example how it can look in Azure DevOps:

[image: Pipeline]